# Callkit present Application UI instead of native UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, callkit

I want to use Callkit framework to present iOS native UI in incoming call for my voip app when smartphone is locked (more efficient than a simple notification), but after answering I would like to go to my app UI instead of one provided by callkit.

Preferentially I would like go immediately after answering the call, 2nd option would be a option in callkit UI to move to my app.

Any idea if that is possible? Didn't figure out any solution till now.

Thank you
Jose

Comment: "2nd option would be a option in callkit UI to move to native app" What is mean by Native app?

Comment: From the lock screen, after answering the call immediately you can't move to App UI. In callkit UI, there is a button to move to App UI.

Comment: Thank you @RJVKumar, its was an error in question, it should be "my" app instead of "native" app. About your answer, it is valid so I think you could post it, this button is a plan B. Although I still have the problem that it would be nice to make this change automatically, without need to press the button.

Answer (score 4):

> CallKit provides the calling interface
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

Unfortunately there is no way to control calling interface for an incoming call.

When the device is locked, user will see native call UI after answering the call. If they wish to move to your app, they will have to tap corresponding button ("Messenger" button on the screenshot below):
[image: messenger call ui]

When the device is unlocked, however, user will be redirected straight to your app automatically once they accept the call, so there is that.